# How can I 'group' multiple functions into separate objects within a class in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Ok so basically this example class to show you what I've done

```
Public Class TopLevelClass
    Private Property _Object1 As Object
    Private Property _Object2 As Object

    Public Sub New()
    ...
    End Sub

    Public Function FunctionOfObject1()...
    Public Sub FunctionOfObject2()...
End Class
```

Now, this is what I want it to act like:

```
Public Class TopLevelClass

    Public Structure/Module/? Object1
        Public Function FunctionOfObject1ThatIveCreated()...
    End Structure/Module/?

    Public Structure/Module/? Object2
        Public Function FunctionOfObject2ThatIveCreated()...
    End Structure/Module/?
End Class
```

I basically want to be able to group certain functions together, but I do not want to have to initialise them as a class.

I've tried going down the 'create them as a class' route, but the code just doesn't allow for it, and I can't see inside the code to work out what's going wrong, and I can't just use the code that's already visible to me in the objects, because quite frankly they are truly awful.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What you describe sounds pointless, which would explain why how to do it is not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

To Group certain function together you can use nested classes. Create your class as follow

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Class ClassA
        Public Shared Function functionA1()
            Return "FunctionA1"
        End Function
        Public Shared Function functionA2()
            Return "FunctionA2"
        End Function

    End Class
    Public Class ClassB
        Public Shared Function functionB1()
            Return "FunctionB1"
        End Function
        Public Shared Function functionB2()
            Return "FunctionB2"
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

to use these functions you can call it directly without initializing the parent class object thanks to **Shared** modifier in vb.net.

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.ClassA.functionA1)
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.ClassA.functionA2)
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.ClassB.functionB1)
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.ClassB.functionB2)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The question here is what point does the patent class actually serve? It appears to serve the role of a namespace and thus should just be a namespace.